# Windows Server vs Desktop

Tags: windows

A friend's company (<5 employees) runs a POS application (.Net on Windows Desktop OS) that uses an object-orientated database (Cachè from Intersystems). The server is a quite old D820/8Gig/HDD which runs under Win2k server. The DB server is going to be updated to 64bit during the next month. At the same time, my friend also wants to upgrade the server (i5-4570/8Gig/SSD), but instead of using a server OS I suggested (for cost reasons) to use Win7-Pro/64. The software vendor "demands" that the OS should be a server OS (reason: beacause it's a server ...), though they really can't explain why. The only reason they came up with, was the limited number of "connected" users. Win7 allows 20 (afaik) and that exceeds the number of possible clients by a factor of 3.
Is there any "good" reason, why one should use a Windows Server (there's no need for ADS, user management, DHCP, ... etc), if the only server functionality needed is a (third party) database server? I mean: We are not talking about W2k-Srv vs Win98-Dt, do we?

Funny sidenote (imho): The hardware offer of the software vendor (of the POS app) included a server with server OS and a second (fallback, emergency) machine with Win7-Pro. If there setup really would need a server OS, why would they offer a desktop OS for the fallback-server?

Comment: You can use the free virtual machines that Microsoft provides to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of differences between the Server and Desktop versions of Windows, but it doesn't sound like any of that matters here.

However, you have a non-technical reason for using the recommended configuration.  If this company won't support their software, you don't want to end up in a situation where it doesn't work properly and their support simply blames you.  I've never seen any of that proprietary stuff perform flawlessly... it's always problematic.  You might want to buy a copy of Windows Server just to keep your support contract usable.

Comment: I'll stick to the first part of the answer in case nobody else finds a technical reason ;)